# st-terminal / vim - Ultisnips: How to enable Ctrl+Enter as Enter in insert mode of vim?

Tags: vim, xterm, suckless-terminal

I get a strange behavior of vim but it can be related to st-terminal that I cannot do an <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to break the current line into new line in **insert** mode, as in the example below:

I have a line in vim that opens inside st-terminal:

```
This is a| test
```

`|` is the position of the cursor. I'd like to break the line into two different lines using <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> but I couldn't do that; vim somehow prevents me to break the line.

```
This is a
test
```

I have settings that might change <kbd>Enter</kbd> behavior of vim, these settings related to “UltiSnips” plugin, like below:

```
inoremap <expr> <Tab> pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" : "\<Tab>"
inoremap <expr> <S-Tab> pumvisible() ? "\<C-p>" : "\<S-Tab>"
inoremap <expr> <cr> pumvisible() ? "\<C-y>" : "\<cr>"
inoremap <expr> <Esc> pumvisible() ? "\<C-e>" : "\<Esc>"

let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<enter>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger = "<tab>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger = "<s-tab>"
```

As I understand, the above code might lock <kbd>Enter</kbd> to break line in insert mode. But doesn't care about <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

UltiSnips possible locked <kbd>Enter</kbd> in insert mode.

I try to install `xterm` and do a try; it doesn't work either.

So it might relate to the OS itself? I have no idea.

I use Arch Linux, st-terminal, xterm, latest vim 8.1 / 1-374

EDIT: I tried to remove the above code in `.vimrc`,
and <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> work again.

But I still need to enable the UltiSnips plugin.
How can I make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> break the line?
It's okay to disable <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

I suspect possible st-terminal didn't separate <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> falls back to <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it actually might had been set to the same "terminal keycodes"??

---

I found a solution: I comment out this line to enable back <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<enter>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Terminal applications expect ***bytes***.  There's no predefined result for <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>, and your question does not contain the information showing what you expect it to be.  Once you decide, you'll have to modify *`st`*'s source-code to send the *expected* sequence of bytes.  (You could do the same with xterm's translation resource).

Comment: Do you mean I have to map `ctrl-enter` to `enter`? Or map `ctrl-enter` to newline `\n` in st-terminal? I need `ctrl-enter` to break newline.

Comment: control+enter == enter (unless someone has an unusual configuration).  It's your choice what to configure, and st is **not** configurable (must edit the program and compile).